# Docker container cannot find path specified in .NET Core project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, path, dockerfile

**Problem description**

Currently, after having build an Docker image successfully and pushed it to Docker Hub. I'm able to pull this image to my Docker Desktop. As soon as I run the image as a container, the container 'exits' due not able to find a path that I defined for a certificate that I need to use inside my Program.cs of a ASP.NET Web API project.

**Expectation**

I expected that the path I defined would be the right path, since in my Dockerfile I'm using the path '/src' where my source files are located. However, this seems not to be the case and I cannot debug in the Docker Desktop logs what the current path is ('pwd' for Linux and I've tried using Debug.WriteLine the following code through my cs code: WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args).Environment.ContentRootPath). Maybe some of you know how to write something to the Dockers Container Logs within Docker Desktop?

**Errors**

I get the following error:

> Unhandled exception. Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file
>    at Interop.Crypto.CheckValidOpenSslHandle(SafeHandle handle)
>    at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.OpenSslX509CertificateReader.FromFile(String fileName, SafePasswordHandle password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
>    at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor(String fileName, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
>    at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(String fileName, String password)
>    at WhatsApp.Auth.IdentityServer.ServicesExtensions.ConfigureIdentityServer(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment webHost) in /src/IdentityService/WhatsApp.Auth.IdentityServer/ServicesExtensions.cs:line 53
>    at Program.$(String[] args) in /src/IdentityService/WhatsApp.Auth.IdentityServer/Program.cs:line 36

**azure-pipelines.yml** *(to give you more insight of what I'm doing)*

P.S. self is repo 'IdentityService' and SharedLibrary is just a core repo that contains various class libraries, which one of them is being used by the IdentityService as a 'Project reference'. Therefore, I need to clone this repo, so that IdentityService can restore .csproj files.

```
parameters:
- name: dockerImageTag
  type: string
  default: 'IdentityService'

trigger:
- main

resources:
- repo: self

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Docker Build & Push to Docker Hub
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - checkout: self
    - checkout: git://<Project>/SharedLibrary

    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Docker build
      inputs:
        containerRegistry: DockerHub
        repository: '<DockerHubRepo>'
        command: build
        dockerfile: 'IdentityService/Dockerfile'
        useDefaultContext: false
        buildContext: $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)
        tags: '${{ parameters.dockerImageTag }}'

    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Docker Push
      inputs:
        containerRegistry: DockerHub
        repository: '<DockerHubRepo>'
        command: push
        tags: '${{ parameters.dockerImageTag }}'
```

**Dockerfile**

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual     Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src

# Copy IdentityService and SharedLibrary projects that are checked out in azure-pipeline.yml to /src
COPY ./ ./

RUN dotnet restore "IdentityService/WhatsApp.Auth.IdentityServer/WhatsApp.Auth.IdentityServer.csproj"

WORKDIR "/src/IdentityService/WhatsApp.Auth.IdentityServer"
RUN dotnet build "WhatsApp.Auth.IdentityServer.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WhatsApp.Auth.IdentityServer.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WhatsApp.Auth.IdentityServer.dll"]
```

**Code I'm using to find the certificate**

```
X509Certificate2 rsaCertificate = new X509Certificate2(
                "/src/IdentityService/WhatsApp.Auth.IdentityServer/rsaCert.pfx",
                configuration["Certificates:RsaBase64Password"]);
```

I use here '/src/...', because I was thinking to search inside this directory, but without any successful attempts. Also the Linux environments differs from my development environment that runs on Windows 10... Does any of you have a clue how to solve this problem? I really would appreciate it.

Comment: Please do not [delete and repost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74549194/docker-container-cannot-find-path-specified-in-net-core-project#74549194), edit your existing post.